# Does OAuth2 can solve the issue?

Tags: oauth-2.0, cas

I have two web applications at different domains(exampleA.com; exampleB.com).Each web site has its own username/password authentication.

Suppose that there is a URL of exampleB.com in exampleA.com, sometimes I wish when I click the URL ,then directly open the homepage of exampleB.com, and don't input any username/password of exampleB.com after redirecting to exampleB.com.

ExampleA.com uses Apereo CAS 3.5.1, but exampleB.com doesn't use SSO.
I know OAuth2 can be used as a way for users to login in to third party websites, so does OAuth2 can solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and so can any other SSO protocol such as CAS itself. Depending on what B supports you may be able to achieve what you need with either option. CAS might be easier, as long as you can put a CAS client in front of it, and have it read REMOTE_USER for instance.

Comment: B is a PHP application, so I can't put CAS client in B.Also, I can't figure out how to login B without username/password using OAuth, could you give some explanations ?

Comment: You can use the phpCAS client for B.